# dropdown P&T Field Pack - selected option

Tags: field-pack, pt-dropdown

Using a classic html select code Brasil as defaut option could be selected using **selected** parameter:

```
   <option value="África do Sul">África do Sul</option>
    <option value="Brasil" selected>Brasil</option>
    <option value= ............... </option>
</select>
```

I'm using the dropdown of P&T Field Pack, it's working fine, a Channel Field element implement the dropdown list:

```
 <select>
     {options:member_paises}
           <option value="{option_value}"{selected}>{option_value}</option>
      {/options:member_paises}
</select>
```

But how to set Brasil, (or other option) as defaut option, like the classic html select code ??

thanks

Comment: I don't have test install under my hand but try next: <select>
     {options:member_paises}
           <option value="{option_value}" {if '{options:member_paises}' == '' && '{option_value}' == 'Brasil'}selected{/if}>{option_value}</option>
      {/options:member_paises}
</select>

Comment: Max, very nice solution, it's working fine, thanks a lot! If you want, you could put your reply as a answer. regards, stéphane